# can zoom be mixed with multiple y-axis in highstock

Tags: highcharts

We are using high stock and I was trying to combine these two examples

[a base highcharts example](http://tinyurl.com/lf7jpsd)

[a base highstock example](http://tinyurl.com/lfvyx5n)

such that zoom can be used with multiple axis.  This is the result where the y-axis is now all screwed up

[my merged example with literally just one tweak to highcharts code](http://tinyurl.com/mqk8e33)

Is there any way to get zoom with multiple axis working in one chart?  This would seem like a pretty common desire.  (The thing that breaks is the y-axis starts overlapping and stepping on each other when these examples were combined)

thanks,
Dean

Comment: SO was trying to error out so I have to paste long long snippets of code in this post...what a huge pain!!! so I tinyurl'd the links to work around the SO error. Could you imagine putting all 3 of those pages of code in this post....ridiculous.

Comment: But what is wrong with 3rd example? It is zoomed correctly.

Comment: look at all 3 y-axis.  They are overlapping in chrome for me and stepping on each other.  They are nice and separate in the base example.

Comment: In 3rd example the time (x) axis is a bit skrewedup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Highstock loaded to the site, you can create simple Highcharts chart, and enable features from Highstock, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/rP5su/1/

```
        navigator: {
            enabled: true
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
```

Of course that solution requires Highstock to work, simple Highcharts library doesn't contain navigator, scrollbar etc.

Comment: interesting that this fiddle screws it back up just by using the constructor instead... http://jsfiddle.net/C4eYK/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure why the merge doesn't work, but the work around was to specify an offset on each y-axis, 100 for the first axis, 200 for the second axis, etc. which worked around the issue.